# Plot decision boundary from weight vector

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I plot decision boundary from weight vector?
My original data is 2-dimensional but non-linearly separable so I used a polynomial transformation of order 2 and therefore I ended up with a 6-dimensional weight vector.
Here's the code I used to generate my data:

```
polar2cart <- function(theta,R,x,y){
  x = x+cos(theta) * R
  y = y+sin(theta) * R
  c=matrix(x,ncol=1000)
  c=rbind(c,y)
}

cart2polar <- function(x, y)
{
  r <- sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
  t <- atan(y/x)
  c(r,t)
}

R=5
eps=5
sep=-5
c1<-polar2cart(pi*runif(1000,0,1),runif(1000,0,eps)+R,0,0)
c2<-polar2cart(-pi*runif(1000,0,1),runif(1000,0,eps)+R,R+eps/2,-sep)

data <- data.frame("x" = append(c1[1,], c2[1,]), "y" = append(c1[2,], c2[2,]))
labels <- append(rep(1,1000), rep(-1, 1000))
```

and here's how it is displayed (using ggplot2):

[image: link]

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I'm sorry if I didn't provide enough information about the weight vector. The algorithm I'm using is pocket which is a variation of perceptron, which means that the output weight vector [image: weight] is the perpendicular vector that determines the hyper-plane in the feature space plus the bias [image: bias]. Therefore, the hyper-plane equation is [image: equ], where [image: vars] are the variables. Now, since I used a polynomial transformation of order 2 to go from a 2-dimensional space to a 5-dimensional space, my variables are : [image: newvars] and thus the equation for my decision boundary is: [image: neweq]
So basically, my question is how do I go about drawing my decision boundary given [image: weigh]

PS: I've found a solution while waiting, it might not be the best approach but, it gives the expected results. I'll share it as soon as I finish my project if anyone is interested. Meanwhile, I'd love to hear a better alternative.

Comment: The decision boundary will depend on the model that you generated.  Please also include the code for your polynomial model.

Comment: @G5W I edited my question. BTW, it doesn't matter what library you use as long as it gives the expected results. Thank you!